# Delphi XE6 Firemonkey: StyleLookup inherit text value as well

Tags: styles, firemonkey

I am using styles for first time and get strange behavior.
The font properties etc inherit fine but my text value is replaced with the text value from the referenced TLabel.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
km = new TLabel(Bord);
km->Parent = Bord;
km->Position->X = 42;
km->Position->Y = 7;
km->Width = 38;
km->Height = 14;  //up to here these properties are fine
km->StyleLookup = "style_km"; //inherit style from other TLabel
km->Text = "9009 km"; //this is ignored - the text from other TLabel displays at runtime
```

Comment: this code you posted works just fine so you screwed up a style, most obviously `style_km`.

Comment: my problem is not with the style it is with the text value

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you've done here is put a label on the form and set it's StyleName to 'style_km', then put a second label and set the StyleLookup to 'style_km' to make it look like the first label.

However, when you make a component into a style, as you are doing with the first label, the componnt(s) which use the style will inherit *all* the properties of the style which, here, includes the text.

Also the style for a TLabel should be a TText[1]. A TLabel knows to look for a TText and to set it's text into a TText. It doesn't know what to do if the style is a TLabel (i.e. different component and which doesn't inherit from a TText).

What you need to do is put a TText on the form, somewhere where it won't be seen, and use that as your style.

But bear in mind that putting styles on a form is not the ideal what if creating a style. It is great for learning about styles, since it's a quick way to create and play with them but the need to hide the components etc. means it's not ideal for production use.

If you're developing for desktop, right click a TLabel and select 'Edit custom style' which will copy the current style to the style designer for you to edit.

On mobile you'll need to add a TStyleBook, set the StyleBook property of the form to point to it and double click the TStyleBook to create a style from scratch.

[1]Some styles, especially on mobile need something other than a bog standard TText for text items.